# Convert SVG To PDF Retaining "embedded" images

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, svg

I'm looking for a way to convert an SVG to PDF in Javascript that works with `<image>` tags in the SVG. So far the SVG to PDF solutions I've tried just show a blank image where the `<image>` should be. This includes SVG-to-PDFKit: https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit#readme

I've tried with a link as the href value, and base64 encoding. I've tried free online SVG to PDF converters as well, all of which generated a blank image. The other shapes and paths in the file remained correct, it's just `<image>` elements giving me trouble.

Comment: My intent was to convert the SVG to PDF because a client currently uses PDF files of 1200 DPI to send to their printer (UV printer I think). But are you suggesting don't bother with the conversion? They should be able to print from SVG...